# Ubuntu 14.04 - Wi-Fi disconnecting after minutes

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet

I'm new to the Linux world and I recently bought an Ubuntu 14.04 integrated laptop.

I have a problem with my WiFi connection. It looks like ti's working fine, but after 1/2 minutes the connection goes down without any sign. The wireless connection remains connected but I cannot navigate the web, so I have to start it again manually.

This occur when I stay 3/4 meters from the router. When I stay in front of the router I don't have any problem of connection and everything work fine.

How can I increase the reliability of my connection when I move away from the router?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `lsusb&&lspci`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's working based on where you stand, a couple of things to try out..

1. wifi doesn't pass metal, make sure the router is not obstructed by
   wire mesh, home electronics, maybe walls.
2. if your router has antennas, please put your laptop in the non working position, and play with the antennas, and see the signal
   strength
3. Try different bands in the router, or try 5Ghz spectrum if is supported. 2.4Ghz tends to get busy in apartment buildings.
4. Check if you don't have conflicting equipment running, such as bluetooth ( other wifi router perhaps in the cable modem, cellphone, that might overlap your wifi)
5. If the router is old or weak, it might be the case that if you open too many connections it puts the router under too much load. Check your browsing habits.
6. Make sure you run a wpa2 encrypted channel and you don't have rogue users stressing your router..

Answer (score 0):

Some time wireless channel could also be a problem. Please change your wireless channel and check the reported issue

Set your wireless channel in the router to 11 and then save the router configuration and reboot it.

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 11
```

Hope this helps!